# How to disable Android Randomized MAC upon EMM enrollment

Tags: android, provisioning-profile, mdm, android-11, emm

We are using something similar to the snippet below to generate a QR code which is scanned upon device factory reset to enroll our devices into our company MDM.

```
{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID":"WIFI",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE":"WPA",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD":"Password",  
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME":"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver",
   "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM":"I5YvS0O5hXY46mb01BlRjq4oJJGs2kuUcHvVkAPEXlg",
   "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE":{
      "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN":"{Sign In URL token}"
   }
}
```

However, it does not work on android devices with a Randomized MAC enabled. This is because each device MAC is individually whitelisted onto our network; therfore, to connect to our Wi-Fi the Device MAC must be used. Since scanning the QR code tries to connect with the default MAC Address settings, it never connects and requires each user to enroll each device manually instead; such that, they can disable Randomized MAC.

Is there anyway to diable this in the EMM Provisioning JSON itself for a quicker enrollment process?

Comment: Do you find a solution?

I have the same problem.